# SSIS expression builder: convert date/time to Epoch timestamp

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I'm trying to build an expression to convert a date/time parameter to an Epoch timestamp that will be used in a Url's parameter string.

I figured that I would try `GetDate()` first, then substitute the actual parameter (`@[$Package::endingDate]`).

This syntax:

```
DATEDIFF("s", "19700101", GETDATE() )
```

produces:

> The function "DATEDIFF" does not support the data type "DT_WSTR" for
>   parameter number 2. The type of the parameter could not be implicitly
>   cast into a compatible type for the function. To perform this
>   operation, the operand needs to be explicitly cast with a cast
>   operator.

This syntax:

```
DATEDIFF("s", (DT_WSTR)"19700101", GETDATE() )
```

produces:

> Attempt to parse the expression "DATEDIFF("s", (DT_WSTR)"19700101",
>   GETDATE() )" failed. The expression might contain an invalid token, an
>   incomplete token, or an invalid element. It might not be well-formed,
>   or might be missing part of a required element such as a parenthesis.

This syntax:

```
DATEDIFF("s", CAST("19700101" AS DT_WSTR), GETDATE() )
```

produces:

> Attempt to parse the expression "DATEDIFF("s", CAST("19700101" as
>   DT_WSTR), GETDATE() )" failed. The expression might contain an invalid
>   token, an incomplete token, or an invalid element. It might not be
>   well-formed, or might be missing part of a required element such as a
>   parenthesis.

Is there a way to convert a date/time to an Epoch timestamp, including the timezone adjustments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one :

```
DATEDIFF("SECOND",(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)"01/01/1970",GETDATE())
```